# Смысл точка слэш "./" в обозначении пути

Tags: webpack, пути

Я наткнулся на сей синтаксис в одном и руководств по Webpack. Никак не могу понять что оно значит. Пишут что в целях безопасности оно не выполняет файл, а не команду, но я все еще не могу понять смысл. Так же суть вроде та же что и без указалетей вовсе, так есть текущая папка.

Может ли кто обьяснить смысл этого и зачем я должен это использовать в Webpack, например?

Comment: В линукс так обозначается запуск приложения, причём "./" должны стоять непосредственно перед исполняемым файлом.

Comment: Ничего подобного. В линуксе так обозначается текущий каталог. Команда вида `./somefile` заставляет интерпретатор попытаться запустить на выполнение файл `somefile` из текущего каталога. В отличие от команды `somefile`, которая по умолчанию _НЕ_ ищет в текущем каталоге.

Answer (score 1):

`./` указывает на то,что данный файл лежит в относительной директории,то есть,в той которая указана в контексте.

Comment: Я все так же не понимаю, что значит в относительной? Каком контексте?

Comment: @Telion допустим, если у вас есть скрипт который находится в папке  D:\Scripts\script.ext  и файл который он обрабатывает D:\Scripts\file.txt. Если обращаться к файлу со скрипта по пути D:\Scripts\file.txt - это будет абсолютный путь относительно корневого каталога вашего диска(здесь возможно неправильно сформулировал), если указать путь .\file.txt - это относительный путь, тобиш путь указанный относительно папки в которой находится ваш скрипт. Как в win так и unix системах - "." обозначает текущий каталог относительно текущей рабочей директории. Либо вопрос собственно в другом?

Comment: @Vladimir Yaremenko "путь указанный относительно папки в которой находится ваш скрипт" что это значит? Можно ведь вовсе без ничего прописать и будет тот же путь начиная с текущей директории?

Comment: @Telion в зависимости от ситуации, и конфигурации системы "file.txt" может запустить программу для открытия файла file.txt ".\file.txt", явно указывает что это ссылка на файл, а не запуск самого файла. Как реальный пример можете прочесть о разнице между raw_input() и input() в python2.x.

Comment: @Vladimir Yaremenko значит если написать `./` в консоли то ничего не произойдет, но если прописать его, например в том же Webpack, то он сам выбирает что делать с файлом, в часности передавая ссылку другим модулям что бы те могли их запускать. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Telion в принципе, да. Это сделано для перестраховки в целях безопасности, для защиты от разных shell injection. Лучше перебдеть чем недобдеть) Но это только мои рассуждения, и они не обязательно являются 100% верными.

Answer (score 0):

С древних времён в операционной системе `unix`, и во всех совместимых с ней (а также в `dos` и позднее в `windows`) в каждом каталоге есть два специальных виртуальных подкаталога: `.` и `..`. `.` — это сам каталог, `..` — это родительский.

Пути `/a/b/c/`, `/a/././b/./././c/.` и `/a/b/../b/c/../c/` Указывают на один и то же каталог.

Если путь начинается с `/` это значит, что он идёт относительно корневого каталога, и называется абсолютным, в противном случае путь отсчитывается от текущего каталога и называется относительны.

Теперь о безопасности.

В unix-подобных операционных системах (в частности linux) программу можно запустить двумя способами.

1. Указать имя программы. Тогда саму программу операционная система будет искать в одном из заранее определённых каталогов, один из них `/usr/bin`.
2. Указать путь и имя программы. Вместо `cd <каталог>` можно ввести `/usr/bin/cd <каталог>` и получите тот же результат. Путь нужно указывать, если у вас есть несколько одноимённых программ или если она расположена вне заранее определённых каталогов для программ.

Если мы указываем имя программы без пути, она никогда не пытается запуститься из текущего каталога (в отличии от `dos` и `windows`) именно в целях безопасности. Если хакер обманом уговорит пользователя скачать программу с именем `cd` и положить её в свой домашний каталог (а только туда у пользователя есть право на запись), то выполнение команды `cd <каталог>` (в том числе и из скрипта) не приведёт к запуску кода хакера.

Но чтоб пользователь всё-таки мог выполнить свой код доступен второй способ с путём. Можно указать полный путь, а можно перейти в папку программы и указать путь `./<имя файла>`, который превратится в `<полный путь к текущему каталогу>/<имя файла>`

Answer (score 0):

`./hello`   запуск скомпилированного файла, где `./` пишем потому что в принципе `hello` - это такая же программа для системы, как и `mv`, `cp`, `cat`, и когда мы их вызываем, система ищет их в папках, которые можно посмотреть по команде `echo $PATH`. А когда мы пишем `./hello` мы указываем что запускать нужно из текущей папки.